# Piwik MySQL Driver Not Installed

Tags: mysql, database, web-analytics, matomo

I have a strange error appearing whenever I try to access my [Piwik analytics](http://piwik.org).

It has been working fine for months and I haven't upgraded anything. The only change was that my account was 'on hold' for a few weeks due a non-payment mix-up. During this time my whole domain was unavailable.

I am on a shared hosting account with JustHost. I have both Joomla 3.8 and Piwik installed there under the one domain, Joomla continues to work no problem.

When is visit `MyDomain.com/analytics` I see the following error message;

[image]

Wondering if anybody would know what this means, or why it's happening. Is there something I should ask my host if they have changed? Surely it would also effect my Joomla installation too though (which it isn't)?

I have tried their support forums however it very quiet over there. It has been suggested to look in the following file `piwik/config/global.ini.php` and check that the database driver is defined, which it is. My config file contains the following;

```
[database]
host =
username =
password =
dbname =
tables_prefix =
port = 3306
adapter = PDO\MYSQL
type = InnoDB
schema = Mysql
```

I have created a `phpinfo()` page located at `MyDomain.com/analytics/phpinfo.php` I can see all the information, if anybody needs me to clarify anything or settings.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused by JustHost's plans: Do they provide a ready-to-use Joomla install or are they selling the mere capability to install one yourself? Also: It would be interesting if there are any relevant overrides in `piwik/config/config.ini.php`. If all else fails, you may want to give the `mysqli` driver a try. And perhaps you should look for rogue `.htaccess` files as well.

Comment: I would gladly do so, however I am puzzled myself on what happened here. This sounds like a serious misconfiguration on you hoster's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no .htaccess file in my MyDomain.com/analytics directory. As soon as I added one it worked!